# Using NDMP as an alternative to CIFS mount

Tags: mount, cifs, ndmp

I have a weird but interesting use-case. I use CIFS to mount shares from a File Server (NetApp, EMC etc) to an application server (win/linux server where my application runs). My application needs to process each of the file from the shares that I mount via CIFS. My application also needs access to the meta-data of these files such as Name, Size, ACLs etc.

I would like to see if I can achieve the same via NDMP. I have some very basic questions regarding this use-case. It would be great if you guys can help me out here.

1. Is this even something which is achievable?
2. Can I just transfer share that interest me instead of entire volume?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is this even something which is achievable?

Theoretically yes, practically no - not unless you want to entirely rewrite your code using a wildly inappropriate API - but technically yes you could, but it's an inappropriate method.

> 2. Can I just transfer share that interest me instead of entire volume?

Certainly NDMP does let you *backup/restore* whole shares instead of whole volumes yes, so if you wanted to do this you would have that level of granularity, but it would still be like completing every third page of your tax return in Latin - achievable but kind of pointless.